# Errors were encountered while processing: eveusb

Tags: virtualbox

Whenever I try to download any sort of package or perform any process, it keeps giving me the error

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 eveusb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm fairly new to Linux and I'm running Ubuntu 22.04. I tried searching the internet but I couldn't find a solution to this. I'm not sure if this is relevant or not, but it said that it had root privileges. A package a previously installed said that it's name is eveusb, but I also read somewhere that it's native to the system. I was trying to download the `bridge-utils` package for virtualbox.